# What are the implications of changing SQL server VM from domain to workgroup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We have Azure VM with SQL server 2019 installed, this is a standalone instance.

I'm tasked with changing the membership of the VM from domain to workgroup. In other words taking the server out of the domain membership.

Our sql server engine and agent services run under the domain service accounts which I'm planning to change to local accounts.

Besides this service account change, is there anything else to consider when performing this change? Has anyone done such a thing before? Is this even possible or supported? I couldn't find any clear Microsoft document on steps to do this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/24960.migrating-sql-server-to-new-domain is about migrating to another domain. Doesn't really say about taking server out of domain.

The other option is install a fresh new SQL server without domain joining, and migrate.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable. Don't forget to update folder permissions for the new service users. But all Windows Authentication users that are from the domain will not work anymore obviously. Keep the machine name the same if at all possible.

Comment: @Charlieface - any reference for the folder permissions for the new SQL engine and agent svc local user accounts? Any reference on handling machine name change (just for my information)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Charlieface - I tried this and surprised to see I didn't have to change any folder permissions. Apparantly this is because SQL service uses internal virtual account which by default (during install) has access to the SQL folders. Reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331488/what-are-the-post-steps-after-changing-sql-engine-and-agent-accounts/335928#335928

Comment: That's because you weren't using a gMSA, which is usually the one of the points of having the machine domain joined in the first place. Yes if you have the same service user then nothing needs to change.

Comment: When SQL was installed everything was default, that is engine running under NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER. Subsequently the SQL engine service account was changed via SQL configuration manager to a domain svc account (mydomain\sql_svc_acc). After this change, SQL worked fine without me having to amend any folder permissions. What has gMSA got to do with this behaviour please?

Comment: Could be when you change it via Config Manager it sets permissions anyway, not sure. Is `mydomain\sql_svc_acc` a gMSA account? If not it should be, as then the password is rotated automatically.

Comment: When I right click on the data and log folders and click on security, then I see the NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER, and not the domain service account, and yet everything just works fine