# What context does the agent service account use (logon account or the NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-agent, service-accounts

My SQL server agent service account is running under the following domain user account: `mydomain\svc_svr1_sql_agent`

I have a ssis package that must be able to read/write files in a folder.

The ssis package is invoked by a SQL agent job. The execution context (the execute as drop-down) is the SQL server agent service account (I am not using the proxy/credentials approach).

Should I configure the folder permissions for agent service account `mydomain\svc_svr1_sql_agent` or the agent virtual account `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT` or both?

The reason for asking this question is that, based on [What are the post steps after changing SQL engine and agent accounts?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331488/what-are-the-post-steps-after-changing-sql-engine-and-agent-accounts/335928#335928), the SQL server engine account accesses the SQL data and SQL log files, etc using the `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` account irrespective of the SQL server engine service account configuration. So I would like to know how if this concept also applies to the SQL agent.

Answer (score 1):

You should give folder permissions to `mydomain\svc_svr1_sql_agent` as under this account SQL Server Agent goes on Windows.

> the SQL server engine account accesses the SQL data and SQL log files,
> etc using the NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER account irrespective of the SQL
> server engine service account configuration.

I don't know why you think so but SQL Server accesses files under it's account (domain account in your case) and the same thing SQL Server Agent does.
Yuo can see this clearly from your backup history if your Agent does backups and you can see this in your data folder permissions.

I attach my folder permissions as a picture

[image]

Comment: You will see here that the engine uses the virtual account irrespective of the logon account - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331488/what-are-the-post-steps-after-changing-sql-engine-and-agent-accounts/335928#335928, hence why I'm having the confusion.

Comment: @variable, I have clustered instance where it is just impossibile use other account than domain account and I assure you all the permissions to all the folders we need to use are given to this domain account, and SQL Server use only this domain account and not virtuale account

Comment: When you right click the SQL data files folder and click on security, then do you see the domain account or the virtual account? Ok my server I see the virtual account.

Comment: I see domain account. For both clustered and stand alone instances

Comment: @variable I updated my answer with the picture. Please check that in Configuration Manager or sys.dm_server_services you see your domain account

Comment: This is interesting. @sepupic - I installed a fresh SQL instance, with default settings. The via SQL configuration manager I changed the engine service account to mydomain\sql_svc_acc, however I didn't change any folder security. The folder security still shows NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER. Yet everything works fine. Is it possible that in your case someone has explicitly added those accounts into the folder security without it actually being required. Why else does my SQL still continue working even though I don't have domain account listed under the folder security?